# How to create more than one databases in a Single app using SQLiteOpenHelper Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I want to store data using threads in SQLite Database. Each thread has its own database to store data. 
I'm using threads to increase performance and decrease processing time. as you know SQLite doesn't allow multi threaded data writing. So I planned to make a database for each thread to save time and increase performance.

Thread1 will insert data in Database[0]
Thread2 will insert data in Database[1]
.
.
.
so on.

How can I achieve this using SQLite Helper?

I'm using this code

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MyDBName.db";

public DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME , null, 3);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}
public void insertdata(int Dbnumber)
{
Database[dbnumber].excquery("Insert into ....");
}
```

Comment: I wonder why are you willing to use two database instead of using multiple tables?

Comment: @Wizard yeah, Good Question. I'm using threads to increase performance and decrease processing time. as you know SQLite doesn't allow multi threaded data writing. So I planned to make a database for each thread to save time and increase performance.

Comment: If you want multiple databases just change DATABASE_NAME from a constant to a regular field that you initialize with a parameter of your constructor.  Then, if the rest of the code is agreeable, you can have as many databases as you want by constructing a DbHelper for each with the name you want.

Comment: @MattGregory please elaborate what you want to say?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you change the constant to a regular class member, like this:

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public String databaseName;

    public DBHelper(Context context, String databaseName) {
        super(context, databaseName, null, 3);
        this.databaseName = databaseName;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Then you can instantiate as many of these as you want:

```
DBHelper db1 = new DBHelper(context, "db1.db");
DBHelper db2 = new DBHelper(context, "db2.db");
```

You might have to change DATABASE_NAME to databaseName in other places in your code, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Create the another class which extends to SQLiteOpenHelper. As simple as that.

Why you need the different thread. When you will create the object of that class it will create all tables for you.

If you want to create the separate thread for each DB use Thread. 
@Wizad suggests what is the need of another DB when you can store multiple tables in DB. 
BTW it's your choice go ahead.

Comment: I'm using threads to increase performance and decrease processing time. as you know SQLite doesn't allow multi threaded data writing. So I planned to make a database for each thread to save time and increase performance.

Comment: You can use database transaction to insert data into multiple table at once and there are other ways also. That is completely different question

Comment: Writing on Multiple tables from multiple threads in a single database will not affect processing?